# How to get the nth Highest mark in all branch?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table Student with fields: `Student_id`, `Student_Name`, `Mark`, `Branch`.

I want to get the nth highest mark and name of each branch with in a single query. Is it possible?

for Example if the datas are

```
S1   |  Amir  |  EC  |  121
S2   |  Ewe   |  EC  |  123
S3   |  Haye  |  EC  |  45
S4   |  Mark  |  EC  |  145
S5   |  Tom   |  CS  |  152
S6   |  Hudd  |  CS  |  218
S7   |  Ken   |  CS  |  48
S8   |  Ben   |  CS  |  15
S9   |  Wode  |  CS  |  123
S10  |  Kayle |  IT  |  125
S11  |  Den   |  IT  |  120
S12  |  Noy   |  IT  |  126
```

And I am selecting to display the third highest mark in each branch the output should be like

```
S1   | Amir   | EC   | 121
S9   | Wode   | CS   | 123
S11  | Den    | IT   | 120
```

Comment: can you post sample data so that we can practically do someething rather then guessing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be much easier if MySQL had windowing functions like several of the other answers have shown.  But they don't so you can use something like the following:

```
select student_id,
      student_name,
      branch,
      mark
from
(
  select student_id,
      student_name,
      branch,
      mark,
      @num := if(@branch = `branch`, @num + 1, 1) as group_row_number,
      @branch := `branch` as dummy,
      overall_row_num
  from
  (
    select student_id,
      student_name,
      branch,
      mark,
      @rn:=@rn+1 overall_row_num
    from student, (SELECT @rn:=0) r
    order by convert(replace(student_id, 'S', ''), signed) 
  ) src
  order by branch, mark desc
) grp
where group_row_number = 3
order by overall_row_num
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/61e56/48)

The result would be:

```
| STUDENT_ID | STUDENT_NAME | BRANCH | MARK |
---------------------------------------------
|         S1 |         Amir |     EC |  121 |
|         S9 |         Wode |     CS |  123 |
|        S11 |          Den |     IT |  120 |
```

Comment: The expected Output is mentioned in the question. I need to get the third highest mark in all branch. In the result given here, it is given wrongly

Comment: @Abi see my edit, I had to reverse the `order by`. It should be correct now.

Answer (score 0):

[MAX()](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/max.php)

```
select branch, MAX(mark) as 'highest mark' from Student group by branch;
```

Comment: [Similar Problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373559/mysql-join-based-on-maxtimestamp)

Comment: this query will give the highest mark obtained in each branch and what i am asking that how it will give suppose 4th highest mark in each branch, and i assume OP is also asking the same ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32100/what-is-the-simplest-sql-query-to-find-the-second-largest-value

Comment: Also refer this tooo http://www.sqlteam.com/article/find-nth-maximum-value-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

`MySQl` does not support `CTE` and also `rownumber`, so you have do something like this :-
Make a temp table , insert data into that then select and finally drop temp table ..

```
create table #temp(branch varchar(30),mark int,row_numbers int)
Insert into #temp
SELECT a.branch, a.mark, count(*) as row_numbers FROM student a
JOIN student b ON a.branch = b.branch AND a.mark <= b.mark
GROUP BY  a.mark,a.branch
Order by  a.mark desc

select branch,mark from #temp where row_numbers=2

drop table #temp
```

This is for SQL SERVER :-

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT  Branch,mark, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Branch ORDER BY mark DESC) AS RowNum
FROM 
student
)
SELECT Branch,mark from cte
WHERE RowNum = 2
```

This will give suppose 2nd highest mark branch wise, you can accordingly choose any Nth level .

Hope it helps :-

Comment: This could take a long time, if my student database contains more than 1L data

Answer (score 0):

This one works in oracle

```
select Student_id,Student_Name,Mark,Branch from (
    select  Student_id,Student_Name,Mark,Branch,dense_rank() over (partition by Branch order by Mark desc) rnk
    from Student ) where rnk=nth_value;
```

nth_value:=nth highest mark needed.
please check this sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7b559/3

Answer (score -1):

You can use Limit to get n highest market ( `limit 1,1 will give you 2nd highest, set as per your requirement`)

```
SELECT mark, name
FROM student ORDER BY mark 
DESC LIMIT 1,1
```

Comment: This will not give branch wise resluts